# Want attached image type page control

Tags: ios, iphone, uipagecontrol

I want below image as page control in iOS, iPhone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to make an image into a page control, but you can use a horizontal UIScrollView with your views embedded in it, then recreate the page control with UIViews for the circles and some resize animations, combined with programmatically scrolling the scroll view. I'm not sure if I answered your question, so if you need clarification leave a comment below this answer.